# How would you express $(\underline{a} \times \underline{b}) \times (\underline{a} \times \underline{c})$ in index notation?

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors

At a guess, I would have said that the answer is $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{jlm}a_{l}b_{m}\varepsilon_{kpq}a_{p}c_{q}$, but I'm guessing that this is incorrect. What is the corrdct expression?

Many thanks.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: It is correct. You might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765361/tensor-notation-practicing) useful, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. If this is correct though, how would you express the product of the three Levi-Civita tenors in terms of Kronecker?